# How do you know which room a user disconnected from?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have an application that can support multiple chat rooms.  I am trying to figure out how to capture which specific room a user disconnected from when they close the browser tab so I can update how many users are joined in a room on the client side.  Right now it seems it's only possible to listen to the disconnect on a global level.  If I get the disconnect event, I can loop through all the rooms the user belongs to via `io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]`, calculate the number of users in the room with `io.sockets.clients(room).length` and emit that to each room.  It seems silly to recalculate the number of people in a room if I don't know for sure that this user left that room.

In addition, I notice that in the disconnect event, `io.sockets.clients(room)` will show the disconnected user still in the array...I have to set a timeout of 2 seconds before that user is no longer in the array.  Is this a known issue?  He still shows `disconnected:false` as well so I am not able to go by that property.

Here is what I have so far:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  //find all rooms this disconnected user belongs too
  var rooms = io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id];

  for(var room in rooms){
    room = room.replace('/','');
    if(room){
      //rooms tend to keep the count around for a while, needs a timeout before user is removed from room
      setTimeout(function(){
        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('count', io.sockets.clients(room).length);
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I might stand corrected, but without really looking at your code in depth I think anyone will struggle to give you an answer to that :S

Comment: There seems to be an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/831) for your trouble.